# Attribute name "onclick" associated with an element type "Label" must be followed by the ' = ' character

Tags: css, jsf

I am facing this error like,

> Attribute name "onclick" associated with an element type "Label" must
>   be followed by the ' = ' character

in NetBeans.

My code:

```
<label class="toggleswitch" onclick> <!-- The onclick attribute is required by iOS -->
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <span class="toggleswitch-inner">
           <span class="toggleswitch-on">On</span>
           <span class="toggleswitch-off">Off</span>
           <span class="toggleswitch-handle"></span>
      </span>
 </label>
```

Comment: I don't know why should iOS need this attribute, but if so, can you add to `onlick` attribute any value? Empty or non-empty?

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` expects a javascript method (or code) that will be executed when the label is clicked

```
onclick="alert('Hello World!');"
```

You can leave it empty, if it is there just to fulfill the iOS requirement: `onclick=""`.

Comment: @BlackBird Sorry if I misunderstood you, but there is no specific question in your post. Can you clarify a bit? Does `onclick=""` fixes the problem?

Comment: actually this is toggle button and css is implements on it.and that onclick is responsible for togglling that button..its works fine with html but got error in netbeans.